# Ambiguous references with the exact same namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first, resharper

The `RC` class is not linked to a database, it is a simple class. The class is at only one place and is not partial. The Aérochem.Domain dll project compiles just fine.

Note: If I select one of the two identical namespaces in the quick fix menu, it does nothing.

Note2: This happens to a couple of classes (some related to a database, some not)

Is there a fix to that or a way to figure what's wrong?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean on the solution?

Comment: Is that Resharper? Sometimes it gets confused and you have to clean and rebuild.

Comment: so lame, i had tried cleaning also but in the end i had to restart visual studio.

Answer (score 46):

I had the same problem. I use ReSharper. The solution to my problem was not cleaning the solution but deleting the `suo`-file.
Hope that helps.

Comment: ReSharper, Options..., General, click Clear Caches and Rebuild All in Visual Studio.

Comment: It happened again.  I think it is necessary to also **restart visual studio**.

Comment: This worked, **provided I also did a rebuild**. (FWIW I also cleared the caches, this may or may not have been important). Just deleting the .suo file was not enough.

Comment: +1 for resharper options -> clear cache -> rebuild all. It works for me.

Comment: Running ReSharper 8.2 in VS2013, this problem popped up. Deleting the .suo file did indeed fix it, so a +1 for you, sir.

Comment: Worked for me.  VS 2013. Resharper.   THANKS!

Answer (score 20):

As for the reference of any future users: This thread covers four answers whereas two are in the comments. I have faced the issue several times, three of these answers have helped me in the past, so if you face the same issue, try any of these:

- Clean and/or Rebuild the Solution then reanalyze the files in Resharper.
- Restart Visual Studio then reanalyze
- Delete the bin/ folder then reanalyze
- (Apparently deleting the suo-file can help, too, although I never had to do that and can't understand how it should help)
- A combination of the three above.

(This is not really a new answer, it is more of a comment on the variety of answers and comments found - it is a community wiki so feel free to adapt it if necessary)

Answer (score 16):

For **ReSharper** users that, like me, don't want to delete their solution's `*.suo` file:

**Clear your caches** via: `ReSharper -> Options -> Environment -> General -> Clear Caches`!

[image: Clear ReSharper caches]

Thanks go to [AUSTX_RJL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/235343/austx-rjl) for his comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21095924/177710). I wanted to give his valuable info more visibility.

Comment: for closing the Vs and Reopen it did the same and fixed the issue with my Resharper intellisence

Answer (score 4):

The `.dll` was already in my `/bin` folder.

When I deleted it, it got rid of this error.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and also ReSharper installed on visual studio.

[image: Print screen 1]

[image: Print screen 2]

I open bug ticket on ReSharper [tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-415687) and the development team advised me to do:

**Solution:**

This problem can be solved by removing the `Solution User Options (.Suo) File`. This file is stored in the project root but is hidden. you need to check `Folder Options-> View-> Show hidden files, folders, drives.` and you need to close visual studio if you have open this project because is used by visual studio.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem while two packages were ambiguously referencing the same dll, and this is what worked for me:

I have given an `alias name` to one of the packages (named Dapper.StrongName), by putting the following into my `.csproj` file:

```
  <Target Name="ChangeNameAlias" BeforeTargets="FindReferenceAssembliesForReferences;ResolveReferences">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ReferencePath Condition="'%(FileName)' == 'Dapper.StrongName'">
        <Aliases>AliasName</Aliases>
      </ReferencePath>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

And then added the `namespace` as `using AliasName::Dapper;`

I added a post here: [Ambiguous extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201437/dapper-ambiguous-extension-methods/55620553#55620553)

See related articles:

- [extern alias (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias)
- [:: operator (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/namespace-alias-qualifer)
- [C# 2.0: Using different versions of
  the same dll in one application](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/abhinaba/2005/11/30/c-2-0-using-different-versions-of-the-same-dll-in-one-application/)

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue in Rider, and going to File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart fixed it for me

Answer (score 1):

For me it was because I had referenced the DLL both by Project reference and Assembly reference. Deleting the Assembly reference fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your project structure contains more than one project under one solution, then you have to delete the content of the bin folder in every project. Doing so solved the error that i was facing.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i have referenced the proyect X inside itself. So the problem wasn't ReSharper (but it was ReSharper who added the reference...)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in a .NET standard project (I call it the host project). The namespace causing the problem was in another referenced project (which was also a .NET standard project) in the same solution.

I did everything: clean, delete resharper cache, close soln, delete .suo, delete binaries. Nothing seemed to work.

Then I converted the host project to .NET framework and then the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a pretty old issue, but maybe this will help someone.  If using c# razor in Asp.Net Core 2+, if you have this problem.

1) Copy the content of the file to notepad.

2) Delete the .cshtml file.

3) Create the .cshtml file with the same name.

4) Copy the content from notepad into the new file

I don't know if this is just a weird bug, or a consequence of upgrading a project from Core 1.0 to 2+, but it FINALLY fixed the problem for me.  This was an issue for me in both Visual Studio 2017 and 2019.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved the same problem by cleaning VS cashe

1. Close all Visual Studio Instances running in your machine. Also, make sure devenv.exe is not running in the Task Manager
2. Delete the Component cache directory -%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\1x.0\ComponentModelCache
3. Start Visual Studio

Also you can try to update resharper to lastest version