# Ambiguous domain with the same path

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, resharper

I am using Visual Studio 2013, with Resharper Ultimate 2015.2, developing a C# .NET 4.5 Console application whose solution space has multiple projects (DataAccessLayer, Domain, etc.)

All of a sudden (this has happened once in the last 3 months but I forgot how I fixed it), one of my C# files gives an Ambiguous Reference error and shows the exact same path.

[image]

Related Article: [Ambiguous references with the exact same namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989983/ambiguous-references-with-the-exact-same-namespace) provided the following solutions:

1. Delete .suo file.
2. Delete bin directories until all projects.
3. Resharper > Options > General > Delete Cache ( then restart VS)
4. Restart VS and rebuild solution

None of these seem to have any effect.  I have checked that the references of the offending project only reference the "ambiguous reference" once.

EDIT:

Found another solution here: [How to make ReSharper re-evaluate its assembly reference highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799074/how-to-make-resharper-re-evaluate-its-assembly-reference-highlighting)   . Basically deleted Resharper Transient data.  Did that.  Still have the ambiguous reference. :(

I created another project with the same Includes, same references and same usages... just a subset and it works just fine !!!!!

EDIT 2:
The file compiles with no error!

Answer (score 0):

In installed Resharper 10 and the ambiguous reference disappeared.