# In msbuild, how can I add a default project reference to a project if it doesn't already have a particular reference?

Tags: .net, msbuild

Most of our company's applications depend on a few core libraries, so there is a build rule in the MSBuild scripts that automatically adds the reference to them:

```
<When Condition=" '$(OutputType)' == 'WinExe' ">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="(project filepath)">
      <Project>{(assembly GUID)}</Project>
      <Name>(project name)</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</When>
```

However, I'm running into a situation where, for a few particular applications, I want to load a different version of those libraries to provide different runtime backings. I can add a reference to them manually, but this build rule will still apply, causing assembly load and duplicate name resolution conflicts.

So, what can I enter as an additional condition that I can use to check the project references that already exist, and thus avoid linking the default project in this build script? If I can't check for project references, is there something else I can add to my code that I can check for?

**EDIT:** Note that this is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39375833/2033557) of mine from a while back - the idea here is that core classes are being replaced entirely and referenced from generated code (this is already being done for different platforms). Yes, this is a very non-.NET way to go about things, but is more analogous to how utilities like Linux's `valgrind` replace `malloc` and `free` to do instrumentation.

Comment: Have you tried checking if ProjectReference contains that specific reference?

Comment: @stijn How do I do that automatically through MSBuild?

Comment: Maybe I didn't think this through; I was thinking of a Condition on e.g. !@(ProjectReference->AnyHaveMetadataValue('Name','(project name)')) but that will likely only work inside a Target. Not sure if that is doable for you.

Answer (score 1):

First remove the ProjectReference items you want to change using the [Remove attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171453.aspx#BKMK_RemoveAttribute), then add the same ProjectReference items with your new meta data (GUID, name etc.)

Comment: This is useful, but isn't quite what I want. The assembly I'm adding manually is different than the one that is added by our msbuild script.